# Convert 2 powershell script to vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

We have 2 powershell scripts. The first one is written for Copy the new Files from SAN to NAS storage and delete older files in destination, as follows:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem h:\destination
foreach($x in $a)
    {        $y = ((Get-Date) - $x.CreationTime).Days
        if ($y -gt 6 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
            {$x.Delete()}
    }
```

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem k:\SourceFolder)
{
    if ($i.CreationTime -gt ($(Get-Date).Adddays(-1)))
    {
        Copy-Item $i.FullName h:\destination\
    }
}

and the Second one is for running Windows ntbackup.exe to backup system state and delete older backup files

```
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

ntbackup backup systemstate /J "Backup Job 1" /F "C:\test\$date-backup.bkf"

$a = Get-ChildItem c:\test

foreach($x in $a)
    {        $y = ((Get-Date) - $x.CreationTime).Days
        if ($y -gt 6 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
            {$x.Delete()}
    }

for security reason I want to use vbscript of these 2 codes for running on my servers. any suggestion we`ll be appreciated

Comment: What kind of "security reason" would that be?

Comment: we have to use "Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned" and this is afraid us for remote execution code that down our server

Comment: Sign your scripts. Here is a [starter article].(http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/16/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2.aspx)

Comment: It's not really for "security reasons" then, is it? It's to subvert security.

Comment: yes, it`s just about security, when we set executionPolicy allsigned it`s a little bit frightening.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to go backwards? Do you fully understand what the ExecutionPolicy is for and how to use it?

The execution policy is more or less for user protection against automated scripts. As the PowerShell Team puts it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/09/30/powershell-s-security-guiding-principles.aspx),

> PowerShell trust user input, and runs it as-is. ...Execution Policies are a user feature. Like seatbelts. It's best to keep them on, but you always have the option to take them off.

I don't follow how it can be "frightening" to set the execution policy? I consider it a bit more frightening to allow users access to the Internet :)

If you are worried about scripts being executed on the server in question, then protect the server by preventing who has direct and remote access to the server.